# Как изменить значение поля перед отправкой формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перед отправкой формы нужно, чтоб значение скрытого input было равно значению из другого input. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста по подробнее. А ещё лучше предоставьте `html` код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие [`submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) у формы

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var value = $('#test1').val()
  $('#test2').val(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://example.com">
  <input id="test1" name="test1" type="text">
  <input id="test2" name="test2" type="hidden">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

За содержание input отвечает jQuery метод .val(). Он позволяет как узнать, так и изменить значение input.